# Android Studio, Buscar dispositivos bluetooth

Tags: java, android, studio, bluetooth

Buenas noches a todos,

Verán, me encuentro con un problema, quiero añadir a mi app la capacidad de listar todos los dispositivos Bluetooth que tengo al alcance y poder emparejarme a ellos.

Estoy mirando proyectos en la red, para hacer pruebas y no consigo obtener ningún listado, eso si, puedo decirles que siempre me topo con el mismo problema: No tengo permisos para BLUETOOTH_SCAN. Ni siquiera añadiendo los permisos al Android manifest logro que permita realizar la busqueda. No les muestro mi código porque realmente ando probando proyectos de ejemplo. Intente tambien el ejemplo de la documentacion de Android https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-bluetooth-devices pero tampoco

En mi proyecto uso la SDK 31.

Simplemente recurro a ustedes por si saben de algún tutorial o documentación con algún ejemplo que me funcione, o bien me aclaren si a parte de añadir al manifest necesito hacer algo mas.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo siento. Las preguntas que buscar recursos externos terminan cerradas. Si quieres ayuda con el código, necesitamos ver el manifest y la parte del código que no está funcionando.

Comment: BLUETOOTH_SCAN requiere petición manual, no unicamente definirlo en el androidmanifest.xml, tu pregunta debe basarse en el problema que tuviste al tratar de "emparejar" dispositivos en lugar de pedir tutorial, ejemplo o documentación, no mencionas cuál es el error, lo cual sería importante.  Revisar [ask], saludos.